# Where is query_posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I use ajax to call a function in my plugin but failed.
It says,
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function query_posts() in D:\wamp\www\wp-content\plugins\postCrawler\AjaxActon.php on line 3"

AjaxActon.php is like this:

```
<?php
     $pageSize=$_POST['pageSize'];
     query_posts('posts_per_page='.$pageSize);
?>
```

Then I try to use include_once() to load it.But the peoblem is where the query_posts() method exists.
P.S. I've tried to search from post.php (wp-admin/includes) but there is no query_posts method here.
So, where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try including wp-load.php. This file resides at the root.

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are not writing ajax request with the right and proper way, You don't need to call any file with the ajax method in your plugin, just define a action

```
var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
    whatever: 1234
};

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
```

and then call your ajax action through `wp_ajax_` action hook.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {

     global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

     $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
     $whatever += 10;
     echo $whatever;

     die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

#### Through this way you can access all the wordpress's functions

Here is the link for more information: [AJAX_in_Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)